# Pandas: group with TimeGrouper

Tags: python, pandas

I have data

```
i,ID,url,used_at,active_seconds,domain,search_term  
322015,0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca,vk.com/antoninaribina,2015-12-31 09:16:05,35,vk.com,None    
838267,0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca,vk.com/feed,2015-12-31 09:16:38,54,vk.com,None  
838271,0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca,vk.com/feed?section=photos,2015-12-31 09:17:32,34,vk.com,None   
322026,0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca,vk.com/feed?section=photos&z=photo143297356_397216312%2Ffeed1_143297356_1451504298,2015-12-31 09:18:06,4,vk.com,None    
838275,0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca,vk.com/feed?section=photos,2015-12-31 09:18:10,4,vk.com,None    
322028,0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca,vk.com/feed?section=comments,2015-12-31 09:18:14,8,vk.com,None  
322029,0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca,megarand.ru/contest/121070,2015-12-31 09:18:22,16,megarand.ru,None  
1870917,0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca,vk.com/feed?section=comments,2015-12-31 09:18:38,6,vk.com,None 
1354612,0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca,vk.com/antoninaribina,2015-12-31 09:18:44,56,vk.com,None
```

I need to group by `ID`, and next groupby `used_at`, where difference between 2 strings more than `500 second`.
I try

```
df.groupby([df['ID', 'used_at'],pd.TimeGrouper(freq='5Min')])
```

But it returns `KeyError: ('ID', 'used_at')`

Comment: can you try `df.groupby([df[['ID', 'used_at']],pd.TimeGrouper(freq='5Min')])` you need to pass a list of strings, what you tried to pass was in effect a tuple hence the keyerror

Comment: @EdChum `ValueError: Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional`

Comment: does `df.groupby([df[['ID', 'used_at'],pd.TimeGrouper(freq='5Min')])` work?

Comment: @EdChum it return `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIUC you need:

```
print (df.groupby('ID')['used_at'].diff().dt.seconds)
0     NaN
1    33.0
2    54.0
3    34.0
4     4.0
5     4.0
6     8.0
7    16.0
8     6.0
Name: used_at, dtype: float64
```

If you wish to use `TimeGrouper`, you should first set a `Datetimeindex` and then you can use any aggregating function - e.g. `sum`:

```
df['used_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df.used_at)
df.set_index('used_at', inplace=True)
print (df.groupby([df['ID'],pd.TimeGrouper(freq='5Min')]).sum())
```

Another way to do it is to copy the column `used_at` to `index`:

```
df['used_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df.used_at)
df.set_index(df['used_at'], inplace=True)
print (df.groupby([df['ID'], df['used_at'],pd.TimeGrouper(freq='5Min')]).sum())
```

Comment: code with `TimeGrouper` return `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'`

Comment: Seed edit, maybe need convert `string` column to `datetime`.

Comment: thank you! Can toy see my another question. please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38269617/group-data-with-condition-using-pandas